# Drop and drag как переместить весь обьект по клику?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем доброго дня) делаю dnd на чистом js.
так у меня есть вот такой список
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос как сделать по клику плюса(красное выделение), чтобы переместилось весь синий блок?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данный момент у меня по клику само плюс перемешается а потом весь блок и это очень не красиво(((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    $items, node => {
      node.onmousedown = mouseDown;
      node.onmouseup = mouseUp;
    }
  );

function mouseDown(e) {
    if (hasClass(e.target, handle)) {
      $selectEl = e.target.parentNode;
      $selectEl.draggable = true;
      on($root, 'dragstart', _dragstart);
    }
  }
function _dragstart(e) {
    console.log('mouseDown', e);

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', $selectEl.innerHTML);

    on($root, 'dragover', _onDragOver);
    on($root, 'dragend', _onDragEnd);
  }

  function _onDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    const target = e.target;
    if (target && target !== $selectEl && target.dataset.item) {
      const active = getNextElement(e, target);
      $root.insertBefore($selectEl, active);
    }
  }
```

Comment: У вас пример кода не рабочий :(

Answer (score 0):

В общем, идея такая. При нажатии на хендлер, весь элемент становится `draggable = true`, при завершении `draggable = false`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(makeDraggable);

function makeDraggable(item) {
  item.querySelector('.handler').addEventListener('mousedown', () => item.draggable = true);
  item.addEventListener('dragend', () => item.draggable = false);
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.item .handler {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="handler">H</div>
</div>
```